# Is an image within a noscript tag only downloaded if Javascript is disabled?

Tags: html, http, background-image, image, noscript

Consider the following example:

```
<noscript>
    <img class="photo" src="example.png">
</noscript>
```

Does the client only download the image file if they have Javascript disabled? (I'm aware the client can only see the image if Javascript is disabled in this example)

The reason I'm asking is because I've been using base64 data URIs for several background-image properties in an external CSS (avoiding http requests). I would like to also use base64 data URIs for the src value of some img tags by updating their values via external Javascript (to retain benefits of caching).

Essentially, the whole point of this is to avoid/limit http requests and so I was wondering if    I can degrade gracefully and only fetch the image files if Javascript is disabled? Or is the image downloaded regardless?

Comment: What do you mean by *"updating external values via external Javascript"*?

Answer (score 18):

**Short Answer:**
**NO, images are NOT downloaded inside a `<noscript>` element**

**Technical Answer:**

I had just been doing some testing on my personal website for functionality with JavaScript disabled, and came across this article… with JavaScript still disabled, btw.

Well, at the very top of this web page, Stack Overflow have a warning message which states:

“Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled”

Being the type of web geek who tends to “view source” at practically *every single website* I look at (!), the HTML code for the message is as follows:

```
<noscript>
    <div id="noscript-warning">Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled<img src="http://example.com/path/to/1x1-pixel.gif" alt="" class="dno"></div>
</noscript>
```

Nothing too ground-breaking there. However, what interested me was the `IMG` element, which referenced a 1px by 1px invisible image.

I am *assuming* that this image must be used by analytics/statistics software to detect how many of their users are browsing without JavaScript. If this assumption *is* correct (and there isn’t any other reason for using a blank 1x1 pixel image here that I’ve overlooked here), therefore this would basically confirm the following: **browsers *do not* download the contents of anything within a `NOSCRIPT` element**, *except* in the situation that *JavaScript is actually disabled*. (And there certainly does not seem to be any retro ’98-style layout techniques going on, I am glad to say!) ;-)

(P.S. – I hope that I don’t somehow offend anyone at the Stack Exchange network for pointing this out!)

Answer (score 14):

The HTML 4.01 specification says just that the content of `noscript` is not rendered in certain situations. However, this suggests that browsers should not perform any GET operations on the basis of its content in such situations, since such operations would be pointless and would reduce efficiency.

The HTML5 draft is more explicit and probably reflects actual browser behavior. It says about the [`noscript` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element), in an emphatic note: “it works is by essentially ‘turning off’ the parser when scripts are enabled, so that the contents of the element are treated as pure text and not as real elements”. (The note relates to why `noscript` does not work when using the XHTML syntax, but it also reveals the principle by which it works, when it works.)

So we can expect that when scripting is enabled, the content of `noscript` won’t even be parsed (except to recognize the end tag). Blender’s answer seems to confirm this, and so does my little experiment with Firefox:

```
<img src=foo style="foo: 1">
<noscript>
<img src=bar style="bla: 1">
</noscript>
```

Firefox makes a failing GET request for `foo` but no request for `bar`, when scripting is enabled. In addition, it shows a warning about erroneous CSS code `foo: 1`, in the error console, but no warning about `bla: 1`. So apparently the `img` tag was not even parsed.

However, I don’t see how the question relates to the scenario presented as a reason for asking it. I think you use an `img` element outside `noscript` and put there, using `data:` URL, the desired initial content (which will remain, as fallback, the final content when scripting is disabled).

Comment: sorry, but how is a `data:` URL pattern content-accessible when js is not enabled?

Comment: @Ben, `data:` URLs do not depend on JavaScript; they are just URLs parsed by the browser.

Comment: Can a crawler parse the image inside noscript? Or is there some other way to let crawlers index images that are otherwise downloaded through JavaScript?